# Getting a specific attribute instance using ConditionString

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, getcustomattributes, conditional-attribute

This might be a silly question. I am trying to understand the concept of conditional attribute.My aim is to get a specific attribute instance and ended up in getting NullReferenceException instead of the output "CONDITION1".

```
class Program
    {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Getting a specific attribute instance
        ConditionalAttribute conditionalAttribute =
            (ConditionalAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (Class1), typeof (ConditionalAttribute));
        string condition = conditionalAttribute.ConditionString;
        Console.WriteLine(condition);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        [Conditional("CONDITION1"), Conditional("CONDITION2")]
        private static void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mymethod");
        }
    }

    }
```

I hope i am using right attributes in the GetCustomAttribute. Can someone point out where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class don't have `Conditional` attribute,your method marked with `Conditional` Attribute.So you need to get your `Method` first,then get the Attribute(s)

```
var attributes = typeof(Class1)
                .GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                .GetCustomAttributes().OfType<ConditionalAttribute>()
                .OrderBy(a => a.ConditionString);
foreach (var at in attributes)
{
     Console.Write(at.ConditionString);
}
```

Comment: @Rashmi your method is private I think that is the problem.I have updated my answer try again

Comment: Yes, you are right. Method was private. Thanks for pointing out and helping me to understand the topic. It prints the output in reverse order: CONDITION2CONDITION1

Comment: @Rashmi you can easily use OrdeyBy method, `OrderBy(a => a.ConditionString)`

Comment: Yeah, can use OrderBy to solve this. I was interested in knowing why "attributes" variable is storing values in reverse order.(Why on stack?)

Comment: I tried,and I get this output without using orderby: `"CONDITION1 CONDITON2"`

Comment: Without orderby, it is CONDITION2CONDITION1.       class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            var attributes = typeof(Class1).GetMethod("MyMethod").GetCustomAttributes<ConditionalAttribute>(); foreach (var at in attributes)
                {Console.Write(at.ConditionString);}
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    public class Class1
        {
        [Conditional("CONDITION1"), Conditional("CONDITION2")]
        public static void MyMethod()
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Mymethod");
            }
        }